# android emulator having non english keys

Tags: android

When I run a program on my android emulator most of the keys are in English.  However, on both lower corners there are buttons that look like they are from an Asian language.  Also, I am using textAutoCorect, but only Asian characters pop up instead of English words.  I know it is not my code, so how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this happening when you type into a textedit or something? if so then you want to long click onto the textedit and then select input method and then android keyboard.

Comment: Thanks, I am learning both how to program an android and how to use one